# How to auto update the flask webpage?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

Hi I am currently having a project with python flask on Raspberry Pi.
My project will include some physical component such as sensor and motor. Now I like to perform some task when a 'start' button from the web page is pressed, and that function which the button called will keeps looping until another 'stop' button is pressed. Within the looping task, result will produce and I will need to update the result back to the web page at the same time which not stopping my looping task.
Below is what I'd tried, I am trying a solution with "context_processor" but I am not very understand with the working and not sure is that the true solution which solve my problem.

```html
{% block body %}
<form method="POST">
    <label style="font-size: 20px;"> A : {{ output_img }}</label>
    <br/>
    <label style="font-size: 20px;">B : {{ output_value }}</label>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="StartBtn">Start</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="StopBtn">Stop</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
@app.route('/about', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def about_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "user" in session:
            user = session["user"]
        else:
            return redirect('/')
        
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'StartBtn':
            print("Start Pressed")
            testloop()
            return redirect('/about')
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'StopBtn':
            print("Stop Pressed")
            return redirect('/about')

    else:
        return render_template('about.html', message="")
```

From above python code, when the "Start Btn" is pressed, my code will jump into a function which shown below and keep looping over that function, after that when the user pressed "Stop Btn" is pressed, the looping function will stop.

```html
def testloop():
    global output_value, output_img
    a = 0
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(3)
        output_value = str(a) + ' value'
        output_img = str(a) + ' img'
        print(a)
        a = a + 1
```

and last but not least, this is my "context_processor" code.

```html
output_value = ''
output_img = "/static/pics/noimage.jpg"
@app.context_processor
def context_processor():
    global output_value, output_img
    return dict(value=output_value, outputimg=output_img)
```

I hope I had explain my problem clearly. Thanks for the help!

### Update, below picture may help me explain clearly about my problem.

[image]

As what I understand, when the user pressed a button, the server will run for that particular function, after returning the result to the client site (webpage) the server will stop running and wait for another command. How can I get one command from the button and keeps the server running in a loop and pushing the result time to time back to the client site within the looping?

Comment: So the looping function will stop? Or doesn't? Did you already consider using sockets (eg flaskio)

Comment: the looping function will stop when the 'Stop Btn' is pressed, I have not write that part of code yet, but that will be my objective of the whole web page. sockets? I never try it before, can u explain briefly about it or show some coding steps to me? thanks!!!

Comment: You can look up Sockets to understand it completely. To give you a small explanation: Sockets are connection that are opened once in the beginning but keep open. So once you load a webpage, you don't need a refresh to get new content. One of the most famous examples is a chat page. Where reloading the page isn't necessary to get more chat messages. In your case, data will be updated on the fly. What's most annoying is that you're have to refactor some major things to use Flask Io instead of Flask.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I've been trying to understand socketio but maybe I am too stupid to understand it... how actually can I implement socketio into my code to solve my problem? Yes, it will keep turning on the connection but it needs a user to press a button or what to load the result to the webpage right? But for my case, the user will press the button just to start the looping function, leave it running, and i need to auto update the result from my looping function to the webpage. Just like the image i updated in my question, my result will pops out time to time when the looping keeps running.

Comment: as what I understand from these server and client stuff.  When the user pressed a button, the server will run for that particular function, after returning the result to the cient site (webpage) the server will stop running and wait for another command. How can I keeps the server running and keeps on pushing the result back to the client site?